# How to run 2 rails servers in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a scenario where I need to have a rails server listening on 2 different ports. There's a service that's posting a bunch of data to the server and that service can only talk to port 10000. I also need the rails server to listen on port 80 for http requests. Currently, I start the first one (server1) with:

```
bundle exec rails s -e production -p 10000
```

And the second one (sever2) with:

```
bundle exec rails s -e production -p 80 -P server2.pid
```

This works fine for the most part except for one thing.  Whenever I try to load a page using http, server2 will print to console ALL the post requests made to server1 first before rendering my page. It's as if server2 needs to resynchronize with server1 before it can serve my page. I'm wondering why this happens and what the proper way to run 2 servers is.

Comment: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/

Answer (score 0):

installed ngix and forwarded the 2 ports to my server according to https://gist.github.com/jeffrafter/1229497